# Custom Taxonomy Category link

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I seem to go round and round in circles here, I think lack of vocabulary or not knowing what I'm searching for is causing me my problems.

I have a custom post type **projects** and have a taxonomy to reflect that.
When trying to add categories links from this post type in a menu, it links on the site as *domain.com/category/custom_cat*

Ideally, I would like the URL to read: *domain.com/projects/custom_cat*

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Many thanks!

**Edit:**

I think i unfolded one problem and created another, I replaced:

```
 register_taxonomy( 'category', 'project', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Project Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
```

with

```
 register_taxonomy( 'projects', 'project', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Project Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
```

and created a category and assigned it to a project to test it out.   It worked!

However, I have most of the site populated with the old category taxonomy.  How would one suggest repairing the SQL so I can inherit the old category names to the new taxonomy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was a combination of 2 things... as Marvinpoo said but also once changed to honour the existing categories i needed to update the `term_taxonomy` table in MySQL using the following query:

```
UPDATE `wp_term_taxonomy` SET `taxonomy` = REPLACE(`taxonomy`, 'category', 'projects')
```

22 rows were changed in my case and then everything worked silky smooth! :-D

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a taxonomy category for your new custom post type such as

```
function mvli_customtype_category() {

    register_taxonomy(
        'customtype-category',
        'customtype',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Category' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'customtype-category' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'mvli_customtype_category' );
```

And then you can easily open the link like this
`website.com/customtype-category/`

let's say your category is named apple
`website.com/customtype-category/apple`

Now enjoy this code and rename and replace it with your terms.

Comment: Hi, I think I resolved that element of the problem it was retaining the old categories that already exist under the old taxonomy.

Comment: Perfect. Glad you figured it out. :)